# How can i store references to images in firebase database while the images are located in firebase storage

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have stored some profile images of authors in a simple story vuejs application am building. using firestore database i am able to get books title, authors name and the book content but i would like to include an image of the author together with the data am getting from the cloud firestore database.

I recently read that it is possible to store references to images in firebase storage within cloud storage. How can i do this.

i tried going through the docs but i didn't get exactly how to do this.

Comment: "I recently read that it is possible to store references to images in firebase storage within cloud storage." I've never heard of such a feature. Can you share a link to where you read about it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: i got the info from a youtube video, but he was using swift this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5Qp11_QZ0k&t=46s&pp=ygUuc3RvcmUgcmVmZXJlbmNlcyB0byBpbWFnZXMgaW4gZmlyZWJhc2Ugc3RvcmFnZQ%3D%3D

Comment: Does it only work when you first upload the data?

Comment: i stored the references to the images in firebase storage within firebase cloud firestore with an https://....... link eg " https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vuestories.appspot.com/o/storiesImg%2FmanTwo.webp?alt=media&token=01b8f7e2-...... " but am wondering, this methods shows the token in the browser. Will it be a security risk. Thank you guys for all your help